# Installing SP2 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 Express from SP1 to SP2.  Select @@Version reveals 10.50.2500.0

I've downloaded what I think is the correct package but when I try to install I'm prompted to install a new instance or upgrade an existing instance.  Choosing the 2nd option eventually gets me to the point of choosing Mixed Mode or Windows Authentication.  I know what that is, but, why is it asking me this?  I do not want to change *ANYTHING* about my environment other than installing the Service Pack, including authentication mode, or the password of the SA account, etc.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I understand what authentication mode is.  But, this is just a service pack install, not the whole package.  I do not want to change any of the existing configurations.  Why is it asking me this?

Comment: That looks like the right one (Thanks!).  But when I run it I get "There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 Express ***with*** Service Pack 2 (emphasis mine), [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438). This is actually an installer to install an Express instance, not the service pack. The distinction is subtle, but it's important.

Download the Service Pack 2 package independently from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437

You'll want one of these files, depending on whether your machine (or Express instance) is x86 or x64:

> SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x64-ENU.exe
>   
> SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x86-ENU.exe

Running this installer should allow you to select your Express instance as a target of the service pack without offering you options to install a new instance or upgrade an existing instance.

While you're at it, you'll also want to download and install SP2 CU#8:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2871401

Comment: That looks like the right one (Thanks!).  But when I run it I get "There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer."

Comment: Got it, I'd download the 64bit version, but needed the 32 bit instead.  Confusing because OS is 64bit, but SQL Express is 32 bit.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible you tried to patch x86 with the x64 file, or vice versa?

Comment: Oh, yep, our comments crossed paths. Why do you have a 32-bit instance of Express on a 64-bit machine?